# Как добавить атрибут к AsyncMock?

Tags: python, asyncio, pytest

Код:

```
class SomeClass(BaseClass):
    async def async_method(arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
        await self.foo.bar(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2).baz(**kwargs)
```

Один из нескольких используемых вариантов теста:

```
@pytest.fixture
def same_class():
    return SameClass()


async def test_async_method(some_class: SomeClass):
    arg1_mock = 1
    arg2_mock = 2
    some_class.foo.bar = AsyncMock()
    some_class.foo.bar.baz = AsyncMock()
    
    await some_class.async_method(arg1=arg1_mock, arg2=arg2_moc)
    
    some_class.foo.bar.assert_called_once()
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'baz'
```

Кто может подсказать, как правильно протестировать метод?

Comment: Завести асинхронный pytest у меня пока не получилось, но идея такая: baz - это метод от результата вызова метода bar, поэтому нужно указать, что bar возвращает какой-то объект (просто мок), а у этого объекта прописать асинхронный метод baz. Что-то типа такого: `bar_return_value = Mock(); bar_return_value.baz = AsyncMock(); some_class.bar = AsyncMock(return_value=bar_return_value)`. Потом можно проверить `some_class.foo.bar.assert_called_once(); bar_return_value.baz.assert_called_once()`

Comment: UPD. в общем, если оба метода bar и baz асинхронные, то они оба должны вызываться с await, на отдельных строках (либо в одной строке через `await (await self.foo.bar(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)).baz(**kwargs)`). Если bar асинхронный, а baz, синхронный, то в боевом коде `await self.foo.bar(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2).baz(**kwargs)` будет работать, но в тесте если bar асинхронный, но возвращает обычный Mock с синхронным методом baz, то нужно обернуть в скобки `(await self.foo.bar(arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2)).baz(**kwargs)`. В целом, такой код получается: https://pastebin.com/PKnX3rHA

Comment: Пока не полным ответом, потому что 1 - не понятно в итоге оба метода bar и baz должны быть асинхронными? 2 - нужна модификация тестируемого кода, не понятно, допустимо ли это

Comment: `foo` наследуется от модели Tortoise ORM (используется на проекте),  `bar` и `baz` под капотом являются синхронными методами. Возможно, об этом нюансе надо было написать сразу, но я привык, что в описанных выше кейсах такое решается патчингом и т.п. при тестах.

Comment: Ну, под капотом это одно дело, в данном случае важен именно "внешний интерфейс", чтобы понять, чем мокать - обычным Mock или AsyncMock. Пример на pastebin не пробовали?

Comment: Попробовал, но результат такой же. Может быть я что-то упускаю? Максимально приближенный код к боевому и его тест на основе примера с pastebin: https://gist.github.com/mvshvets/467ac61edb699d3ef7b732afcd10afdb

Comment: Мне кажется проще полностью модель на мок заменить, например передавать его при создании `CommissionsService` в `__init__` вместо настоящей модели. Не факт что точно проще, но так по крайней мере больше контроля.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую таким образом поступить